# Natural topology on a group acting on a topological space

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I'm wondering if there is a general way to give a topological structure to a group acting on a topological space. For example, the rotation group $SO(3)$ acts on the space $\mathbb{R}^3$, and it is normally given the subspace topology when you think of it as a a subspace of the collection of $3\times 3$ matrices. Is there a more natural way of arriving at this topology that is coordinate independent?

Here's what I am considering:
Suppose there is a group action by a group $G$ on a topological space $X$. Suppose that for $x\in X,$ $f_x:G\to X$ is a map so that $f_x(g)=g\cdot x.$ Define a topology on $G$ by the minimal topology such that for all $x\in X$, the map $f_x$ is continuous. Explicitly this would involve taking pre-images of open subsets of $X$ under $f_x$ for each $x\in X$ as a subbasis.

Basically I want the action $\cdot:G\times X \to X$ to be continuous. For this to even be possible, the action must already be continuous w.r.t. change in the $X$ component. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Nice! That seems like a stronger version of my idea, replacing points with any compact set. Do you happen to know the motivation for using any compact set for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $X, Y$ are two topological spaces there is a commonly used topology on the set of continuous functions $X \to Y$ called the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology). Under mild hypotheses ($X$ locally compact, which is true here) this describes the [exponential object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+object) $Y^X$ in the category of topological spaces and so has a very pleasant universal property, namely that there is a natural bijection

$$\text{Hom}_{\text{Top}}(X, Z^Y) \cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Top}}(X \times Y, Z).$$

For example, a homotopy between two continuous functions $X \to Y$ is a map $[0, 1] \to Y^X$, the evaluation map $X \times Y^X \to Y$ is continuous, etc. So for $G$ a topological group and $X$ a locally compact space we have

$$\text{Hom}_{\text{Top}}(G, X^X) \cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Top}}(G \times X, X).$$

This implies in particular that if $G$ acts faithfully on $X$ and carries the subspace topology with respect to the inclusion $G \to X^X$, then the action map $G \times X \to X$ is continuous (although it doesn't imply that $G$ is a topological group with respect to this topology!). On the other hand, your proposal only asks for continuity in $G$ for fixed $x \in X$ and doesn't seem to me to get joint continuity.

So, what topology do we get when $SO(3)$ is topologized as a subspace of the space of maps $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with the compact-open topology? We can actually prove a more general fact about the compact-open topology on the space of linear maps between two finite-dimensional real vector spaces, as follows. First, recall that a finite-dimensional real vector space has a unique topology with respect to which addition and scalar multiplication are continuous (which agrees with the product / Euclidean topology if we pick a basis and an isomorphism to some $\mathbb{R}^d$). This is also the topology induced by any norm, and below I'll call it the Euclidean topology.

> **Proposition:** Let $V, W$ be finite-dimensional real vector spaces (with Euclidean topologies). Consider the vector space $[V, W]$ of linear maps $V \to W$, topologized as a subspace of the space $\text{Hom}_{\text{Top}}(V, W)$ of continuous maps $V \to W$, with the compact-open topology. This topology agrees with the Euclidean topology.

*Proof.* We'll use the fact that when $Y$ is a metric space the compact-open topology on $Y^X$ is the topology of [compact convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence). Pick norms $\| \cdot  \|_V, \| \cdot \|_W$ on $V, W$ (which you can take to be Euclidean if you prefer). The Euclidean topology on $[V, W]$ is induced by the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm)

$$\| T \| = \sup_{\| v \|_V \le 1} \| T(v) \|_W.$$

We'll show that the topology of compact convergence, and hence the compact-open topology, is also the topology induced by the operator norm. The topology of compact convergence is, by definition, the topology in which a sequence $T_i$ of linear maps $V \to W$ converges iff it converges uniformly on compact subspaces of $V$. Since every compact subspace of $V$ is contained in a closed ball centered at the origin (which conversely is compact by the Heine-Borel theorem), equivalently $T_i$ converges compactly iff it converges uniformly on closed balls centered at the origin. And since linear maps are homogeneous, by scaling, $T_i$ converges compactly iff it converges uniformly on the closed ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin. But this is the same as converging with respect to the operator norm. $\Box$

(This argument is actually new to me and suggests the nice intuition that the compact-open topology is like a nonlinear generalization of the operator norm, at least if $X$ is locally compact.)

> **Corollary:** The compact-open topology on $SO(3)$, thought of as a subspace of $\text{Hom}_{\text{Top}}(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^3)$, agrees with the Euclidean topology.

Comment: There is a unique structure of topological vector space on finite dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector spaces.

Comment: @Yai: Yes, that's the result I'm referring to when I say "unique Euclidean topology," and I also state it more explicitly in the middle. The upshot here is that the unique Euclidean topology on $[V, W]$ is also the compact-open topology which is nice.

Comment: That clarifies a lot. I do think you may have made a couple typos at the top. I believe you might mean $Hom(X,Z^Y)\cong Hom(X\times Y, Z)$ and a map $[0,1]\to Z^Y.$ The exponential object bit is very useful. Thanks!

Comment: @subrosar: whoops, you're right, thanks. I still can't make up my mind whether to use $Y^X$ for the exponential object or alternatives like $[X, Y]$ or $X \Rightarrow Y$ which have the benefit of putting the codomain first and looking more like a hom functor.

Comment: @subrosar: it is maybe also worth clarifying that the compact-open topology automatically makes $X^X$ a topological monoid (if $X$ is locally compact) but does not automatically make $\text{Homeo}(X)$ a topological group (because inversion is not guaranteed to be continuous), and apparently reasonably nice counterexamples are known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_group#Topology

Comment: I also think its worth highlighting that, because of the universal property you mention, the compact open subspace topology is exactly the minimal topology on $G$ such that the action by $G$ is continuous.

Comment: I think what Yai0Phah might be getting at is that because a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbf R$ (or $\mathbf C$...) has just one (Hausdorff)  TVS structure, you don't really have to show directly that convergence in the compact open topology agrees with convergence in the operator norm topology: just show that the compact open topology makes ${\rm Hom}(V,W)$ a topological vector space and then you're done by uniqueness. It's not as if there are some other potential TVS structures available on ${\rm Hom}(V,W)$.

Comment: @KCd: that doesn't actually seem any easier... I feel like I learned something from comparing to the operator norm so I'm glad I did it anyway.

Comment: @KCd Yes, you are correct. Compact-open topology seems to be the natural topology to put on mapping spaces for TVS. I learned from Scholze's notes on condensed mathematics that the "double dual" of Banach spaces are themselves if we take compact-open topology instead of norm topology, due to the duality between Banach spaces and Smith spaces. By the way, I hit this post when I was searching coherent sheaves over topological rings.